# How to assign argument type score to the parameter type Valuelistenable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to display users' on a settings screen, but getting an error 'The argument type 'Score' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ValueListenable' or only '0' displayed, which is not updated. Here is the snippet of the code that I use in Scaffold:

```
  ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
            valueListenable: score! score,
            builder: (context, score, child) => _SettingsLine(
              'Score',
                // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
                Text('${score != null ? score : 0}') ,
            ),
          ),
```

And here is the header of screen settings:

```
    class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    const SettingsScreen({super.key, this.score});
    final Score? score;
```

Can anyone help me please to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I think it is this if I understood question correctly class Score {
  final int? score;

  final Duration duration;

  final int level;

  factory Score(int level, int difficulty, Duration duration) {
    // The higher the difficulty, the higher the score.
    var score = difficulty;
    // The lower the time to beat the level, the higher the score.
    score *= 10000 ~/ (duration.inSeconds.abs() + 1);
    return Score._(score, duration, level);
  }

Answer (score 1):

Based on the message,you need to provide a ValueNotifer instance on `ValueListenableBuilder`. Then the dataType will be `Score` instead of `int`.

This is the modification you can follow

```dart
final ValueNotifier<Score> score =
    ValueNotifier(const Score(duration: Duration.zero, level: 0));

class Score {
  final int? score;
  final Duration duration;
  final int level;

  const Score({
    this.score,
    required this.duration,
    required this.level,
  });

  Score copyWith({
    int? score,
    Duration? duration,
    int? level,
  }) {
    return Score(
      score: score ?? this.score,
      duration: duration ?? this.duration,
      level: level ?? this.level,
    );
  }
}
```

then use like

```dart
  ValueListenableBuilder<Score>(
          valueListenable: score,
```

And to update, use `.copyWith` method

```dart
score.value = score.value.copyWith(
  level: score.value.level + 1,
);
```

You might also prefer using some state-mangement solution.